# Angular UI router Initialising

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use Angular UI router in my application. When I initialise the UI router instead of getting say, `localhost:8000/#/` I get `localhost:8000/#!#%2F`.

My app.js is as follows:

```
angular
    .module('quiz',['ngMaterial',
                    'ngMessages',
                    'ngCookies',
                    'ngResource',
                    'quiz.routes'
                    ]).config(function($resourceProvider) {
                                    $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
                                    }); 

angular
    .module('quiz.routes',['ui.router']);
```

In my quiz.routes.js I have:

```
(function () {
    angular
    .module('quiz.routes')
    .config(config);

    function config($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('register',{
                url: '',
                templateUrl: '/static/templates/register.html'
            });
    }

})();
```

So instead of the trailing slash I get !#%2F in my  URL. Why is this?

Comment: have you injected quize.routes to your main module?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the code, I forgot to add it here

Comment: Well, I'm not sure enough to write a answer about this. But I think you need to have a url set, in your case '/'... You would only have a empty url if you're defining a abstract state.

Comment: I've posted what is a likely cause, however this may not be the full story, and you may have to adjust your routes and links too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Angular version 1.6, then this is likely because of the changes made to the default hashPrefix which is now set to `!`. To fix, you need to inject `$locationProvider` into your module's `config` block and reset the default hashPrefix back to the empty string.

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')
```

This was [reported as a bug here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15496), although it turns out that it was by design and changed intentionally.

Comment: Oh brilliant. I'm on a slow connection right now so didn't see that you had accepted the answer before I commented above. Pleased it worked.